# Does an ? operator on a non-null property prevent any NullPointerException in the chain?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I'm having trouble understanding the following change to a piece of Kotlin code:

```
package org.example.kotlin.nulll.resolution

import java.util.*

object UtilResources {

    private var properties: Properties? = null

    fun loadProperties() {
        properties = Properties()
        properties?.load(UtilResources.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"))
    }

    fun getProperties(properties: String): String {
        loadProperties()
        System.out.println(UtilResources.properties)
        System.out.println(UtilResources.properties?.getProperty(properties))
        return UtilResources.properties?.getProperty(properties).toString()
    }
}
```

works fine, i.e. returns the property value loaded from `config.properties` or `"null"` in case the property isn't present in the file.

If I change the code to be null-safe to

```
object UtilResources {

    private val properties: Properties = Properties()

    fun loadProperties() {
        properties.load(UtilResources.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"))
    }

    fun getProperties(properties: String): String {
        loadProperties()
        System.out.println(UtilResources.properties)
        System.out.println(UtilResources.properties.getProperty(properties))
        return UtilResources.properties.getProperty(properties).toString()
    }
}
```

I'm getting `NullPointerException` because `UtilResources.properties.getProperty(properties)` is `null` which I'm verifying with the `System.out.println` Statements.

In the first version `properties` is not `null` just like in the second, so the `?` operator is the only thing that's changing afaik. However, it's placed after a non-null property, so it shouldn't have any effect.

`null.toString()` should always work because it's an overloading extension function in Kotlin.

Assume that `config.properties` exists and that `UtilResources.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"` returns a non-null value. You can find an SSCCE project at https://gitlab.com/krichter-sscce/kotlin-null-resolution. It doesn't contain more information than this question.

Please note that I'm not seeking debugging support, I'd like to understand what's going on and broaden my understanding of Kotlin. I didn't manage to condense the example further.

I'm using Kotlin 1.4.31 through Maven 3.6.

Comment: There should be no difference since the `?.` is only used on your property in places where you've already set it to a non-null value. Indeed, when I run your first version of the code, I get a NullPointerException for the same reason as the second. You may want to double-check it.

Comment: Does the NPE on the first version come from a missing `config.properties`? You can use https://gitlab.com/krichter-sscce/kotlin-null-resolution if you want. Everything is set up there.

Comment: `UtilResources.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties")` returns null since I didn't create it. Passing null to `Properties.load()` causes an NPE. The `?.` won't prevent you from passing null. It will only prevent the code from running if `properties` were null.

Comment: Oops, I was looking solely at the `loadProperties` function. Didn't realize you were asking about the code in `getProperties`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first version Kotlin knows that you are calling `toString()` on a nullable type, since you are calling `getProperty()`on the Nullable field `properties`, wherefore Kotlins extension function `Any?.toString()` ist used.

In your second version Kotlin doesn't knows that you are calling `toString()`on a Nullable type, since you are calling `getProperty()`on a field that cannot be `null` and the function `getProperty()` is a Java function that doesn't defines a Nullable return value. Therefore the extension function isn't used and a NPE is thrown if the property doesn't exists.

The following code works as expected:

```kotlin
object UtilResources {

    private val properties: Properties = Properties()

    fun loadProperties() {
        properties.load(UtilResources.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"))
    }

    fun getProperties(key: String): String {
        loadProperties()
        println(properties)
        println(properties.getProperty(key))
        return properties.getOptionalProperty(key).toString()
    }

    private fun Properties.getOptionalProperty(key: String): String? = getProperty(key)
}
```